# Ubuntu 18.04 resets screen resolution on disconnecting external monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have an really annoying problem with Ubuntu 18.04. My laptop has a 4k 15" display. As this makes everything super small, I prefer scaling it down to 1080x1920 when using it. At work I have a dual monitor setup, both connected to a small dock/adapter which I connect to my machine with thunderbolt 3. In my Nvidia X server settings I have configured the dual screens to be next to each other and the laptop screen turned off. Now to the problem.

Whenever I disconnect these displays, my laptop screen turns back on with full 4k resolution. If I go into Nvidia X Server I can change it to 1080 again. But then the next time I connect to my dual monitors again, the setup is all wrong and I have to spend 5 minutes for rebooting and reconfiguring everything correctly again.

Is there a proper way to fix this? Is there a way to change display configurations automatically or maybe with a hotkey or something?

I'm using all the latest updates and Nvidia driver 430.

Here is the output of running xrandr

```
//Only on laptop screen(no external screen connected)

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  50.00    48.02  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4.1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4.2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)


//When Its connected to my dock, laptop screen disabled and two 1080 monitors. 

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   3840x2160     60.00 +  50.00    48.02  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4.1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  75.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-4.2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  75.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you need a script which calls xrandr with the display mode that you prefer. You can then map that script to a hot key.

## The script

I had a very similar issue and after long research [I found this answer by **MestreLion**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500521/linux-retrieve-monitor-names/24933353#24933353). In it they reference a [home-made script which can be found on github](https://github.com/MestreLion/scripts/blob/master/monitor-switch). It is replicated below for archive reason.

You can just copy paste that script in a file called "switch-monitor" with the executable permission activated.

Assuming the file is located in `/home/<username>` you can run the script by typing:

```
/home/<username>/switch-monitor --list
```

This will give you a list of the connected monitors and create a config file `/home/.config/switch-monitor.conf`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# monitor-switch - switch outputs using xrand
#
#    Copyright (C) 2012 Rodrigo Silva (MestreLion) <linux@rodrigosilva.com>
#
#    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program. See <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

declare -A monitor_opts
declare -a monitors

myname="${0##*/}"
verbose=0

# Read settings from config file
config=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-"$HOME"/.config}/"$myname".conf
if [[ -f "$config" ]]; then
    source "$config"
fi

print_monitors() {
    while read -r output conn hex; do
        echo "# $output $conn   $(xxd -r -p <<<"$hex")"
    done < <(xrandr --prop | awk '
    !/^[ \t]/ {
        if (output && hex) print output, conn, hex
        output=$1
        hex=""
    }
    /ConnectorType:/ {conn=$2}
    /[:.]/ && h {
        sub(/.*000000fc00/, "", hex)
        hex = substr(hex, 0, 26) "0a"
        sub(/0a.*/, "", hex)
        h=0
    }
    h {sub(/[ \t]+/, ""); hex = hex $0}
    /EDID.*:/ {h=1}')
}

# if there's no pre-defined monitors list, read from xrandr
# and save them to config file
if [[ -z "$monitors" ]]; then
    while read -r output ; do
        monitors+=("$output")
    done < <(xrandr | awk '$2 ~/^c/{print $1}' | sort)
    cat > "$config" <<-EOF
        # $myname config file

        # List of monitors, from left to right. Edit to your actual layout
        monitors=(${monitors[@]})

        # Extra xrandr options for each monitor.
        # Useful when EDID data does not reflect actual preferred mode
        # Options for non-existing outputs (such as the examples below) are ignored
        # Examples:
        monitor_opts[DFPx]="--mode 1920x1080 --rate 60"
        monitor_opts[DFPy]="--mode 1280x720"

        # As a reference, these were the connected monitors when this config file was created
        # use it as a guide when editing the above monitors list and extra options
        $(print_monitors)

        # For an updated list, run $myname --list
    EOF
fi

message() { printf "%s\n" "$1" >&2 ; }
fatal()   { [[ "$1" ]] && message "$myname: error: $1" ; exit ${2:-1} ; }
argerr()  { printf "%s: %s\n" "$myname" "${1:-error}" >&2 ; usage 1 ; }
invalid() { argerr "invalid argument: $1" ; }
missing() { argerr "missing ${2:+$2 }operand${1:+ from $1}." ; }

usage() {
    cat <<-USAGE
    Usage: $myname [options]
    USAGE
    if [[ "$1" ]] ; then
        cat >&2 <<- USAGE
        Try '$myname --help' for more information.
        USAGE
        exit 1
    fi
    cat <<-USAGE

    Switch monitors using xrandr.

    Options:
      -h|--help          - show this page.
      -v|--verbose       - print in terminal the full xrandr command executed.

      -l|--list          - list connector and monitor names of connected outputs

      -a|--all           - enable all monitors.
      -s|--select OUTPUT - enable monitor OUTPUT, disable all others.
      -l|--left          - enable leftmost monitor.  Alias for --select ${monitors[0]}
      -r|--right         - enable rightmost monitor. Alias for --select ${monitors[${#monitors[@]}-1]}

    Copyright (C) 2012 Rodrigo Silva (MestreLion) <linux@rodrigosilva.com>
    License: GPLv3 or later. See <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    USAGE
    exit 0
}

# Option handling
for arg in "$@"; do [[ "$arg" == "-h" || "$arg" == "--help" ]] && usage ; done
while (( $# )); do
    case "$1" in
    -v|--verbose) verbose=1 ;;
    -q|--no-notify) notify=0 ;;
    -l|--list) list=1 ;;
    -a|--all) all=1 ;;
    -s|--select) shift ; monitor="$1" ;;
    -l|--left ) monitor="${monitors[0]}" ;;
    -r|--right) monitor="${monitors[${#monitors[@]}-1]}" ;;
    *) invalid "$1" ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if ((list)); then
    echo "Connected monitors:"
    print_monitors
    exit
fi

if [[ -z "$monitor" && -z "$all" ]]; then
    usage
fi

# Loop outputs (monitors)
for output in "${monitors[@]}"; do
    if ((all)) || [[ "$output" = "$monitor" ]]; then
        xrandropts+=(--output "$output" --auto ${monitor_opts["$output"]})
        if ((all)); then
            if [[ "$output" = "${monitors[0]}" ]]; then
                xrandropts+=(--pos 0x0 --primary)
            else
                xrandropts+=(--right-of "$previous")
            fi
            previous="$output"
        else
            xrandropts+=(--primary)
        fi
    else
        xrandropts+=(--output "$output" --off)
    fi
done

((verbose)) && message "$myname: executing xrandr ${xrandropts[*]}"
xrandr "${xrandropts[@]}"
```

## The config file

Open the config file created above `/home/.config/switch-monitor.conf`.

```
# List of monitors, from left to right. Edit to your actual layout
monitors=(<list of monitors>)

# Extra xrandr options for each monitor.
# Useful when EDID data does not reflect actual preferred mode
# Options for non-existing outputs (such as the examples below) are ignored
# Examples:
monitor_opts[DFPx]="--mode 1920x1080 --rate 60"
monitor_opts[DFPy]="--mode 1280x720"
```

In it you can change the physical layout of your displays to reflect your set-up and you can define the modes that you want.
So in your case you should change it like so:

```
# List of monitors, from left to right. Edit to your actual layout
monitors=(DP-4.1 DP-4.2 DP-3)

# Extra xrandr options for each monitor.
# Useful when EDID data does not reflect actual preferred mode
# Options for non-existing outputs (such as the examples below) are ignored
# Examples:
monitor_opts[DP-4.1]="--primary --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60"
monitor_opts[DP-4.2]="--mode 1280x720 --rate 60"
monitor_opts[DP-3]="--mode 1920x1080 --rate 60"
```

### The hotkey

Simply follow [this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html) to add a shortcut.
In the `command` box you should register:

```
/home/<username>/switch-monitor --all
```

This will join all your monitors with the given options which were registered in the config file.

Hope this helps :)